# Animate Change View in new IOS

Tags: ios5, animation, uiview, xcode4, switch-statement

i cant seem to figure out how to change the views using animation in the new ios 5. i have this code which just switches the views but without any type of animation. This is the code i have so far:

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
{
    NSLog(@"didTouchDoneButton 5.x");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"didTouchDoneButton 4.x");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

}

Comment: You are explicitly coding to dismiss without animation. Please be more clear what you want to do and why it is not possible the change the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` into `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.

Comment: i want it to animate into a curl or a flip animation. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `presentModalViewController:animated` you can change the animation with the method [[myModalViewController setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle).

Comment: but im trying to go back to the previous view. Not to the next one. Sorry im new to coding so im still trying to understand things.